# How to trigger a unix job on EC2 instance from AWS Eventbridge?

Tags: unix, aws-event-bridge, control-m

I have a unix job on redhat linux server which is being triggered on specified time via Control M tool.

Now, I am migrating the linux server to AWS (ec2 instance). On AWS I don't want to trigger the job via Control M, How I can trigger the batch job in EC2 via Event Bridge?

Or do we have a better solution of Control M tool on AWS ?

I tried different sources - suggesting AWS batch job, not sure how I can use that.